# Replace values in R dataframe based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, replace

In R, I'm using a for loop with an if statement to replace all values in a dataframe that fall outside of a certain range.

```
for (i in seq_along(df$Age)) {
  if (df$Age[[i]] > 90 || df$Age[[i]] < 16) {
    df$Age[[i]] <- NA
  }
}
```

This seems like clunky code. Is there a faster, easier way to do this?

Comment: `df$Age[df$Age > 90 | df$Age < 16] <- NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  There's a command called `replace`:

```
df$Age <- with(df, replace(Age, Age > 90 | Age < 16, NA))
```

Comment: I have four reference books on R that I read through, and I searched extensively online with phrases like "R replace," and for whatever reason, I wasn't able to find that simple solution... so thank you! Much appreciated.